# .htaccess changes for redirecting requests to root of home page to a static html for wordpress

Tags: regex, wordpress, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I have a Wordpress set up which requires redirection when the user enters the root of the site to a static HTML file start.html

```
http://www.myhomepage.com/
```

Redirect to

```
http://www.myhomepage.com/start.html
```

Wordpress adds url rewrites for calls to index.php

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

I only want to redirect

```
http://www.myhomepage.com/
```

and not

```
http://www.myhomepage.com/buy/
```

This will not work as all requests to Wordpress goes through index.php.

```
redirect /index.php /start.html
```

I guess I need a redirect for all pure requests to index.php and not those with query strings. Though I can not figure out how to rewrite it.

The reason is that I want all users that enters the site to get a static html of the wordpress site. Only when the user starts to navigate the site should request be made against wordpress.

EDIT: I required the rule to apply only on GET requests

Comment: Why don't you set [DirectoryIndex](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_dir.html#DirectoryIndex)?

Comment: This was even simpler then the answer below. Add it and i'll accept it aswell. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be done without mod_rewrite, with [mod_dir](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_dir.html) and the [DirectoryIndex](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_dir.html#DirectoryIndex) Directive.

```
DirectoryIndex start.html
```

Comment: I ended up requiring a more advanced solution than that. As I only want it for GET requests and not POST.

Answer (score 1):

Add this line:

```
RewriteRule ^/?$ /start.html [L]
```

just after this line:

```
RewriteBase /
```

Comment: Care to explain it? Guess I need to read up on RewriteRule. The regex ^/?$ matches http://www.mypage.com/ but not http://www.mypage.com/buy/

Comment: You should learn more about regular expressions (regex), they come handy a lot.
the ^/?$ is a regular expression, the ^ matches the start, the $ matches the end, and the ? says that the character before it is optional, so basically the rule matches any URL that contains only a / or nothing at all (the domain name does not affect the rules)

Comment: I know regex quite well I read up on RewriteRule to see how it was applied and I understand it now. What I didn't get is why ^/$ did not work when using http://www.mypage.com/ with a trailing slash.

Comment: Because some versions of apache (the more recent) does not include the slash in the rewrite rule (so basically ^$ should work with or without slash, but I just add the /? to make sure it works everywhere)

Answer (score 0):

In addition to @Oussama solution, as I have a form which posts to itself on the first page. Posting to start.html would not work. I added a condition so that rule only applies to GET requests. That way form post would be sent to index.php as usual.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} GET
RewriteRule ^/?$ /start.html [L]
```

Final file

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} GET
RewriteRule ^/?$ /start.html [L]
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```